# Visual Studio 2017 - Keeps Skipping Tests in Ordered Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-studio-2017

When running an ordered test, visual studio seems to randomly decide when it wants to skip a test. The tests are marked as "Skipped Test" - I've ensured continue on failure is ticked and saved, no tests are marked with the ignore attribute.

The tests work fine when you run them individually or with "Run All", but are randomly skipped when added to a ordered test.

Anyone have any idea what may be causing the "Skipped Test" ?

Comment: If you are using Resharper, try disabling it and seeing if that makes any difference. We had some weird stuff like this happen in the past, and it was Resharper causing it - but I should stress that a later version of Resharper fixed it and the latest version isn't causing us any issues.

Comment: I'm afraid we're not using resharper, so it's not an issue. I've found a temporary fix is to disable "Continue on failure" and re-enable it which seems to let it run, although it's only a matter of time before the same issue occurs which isn't great for scheduled tests.